# How to read all Transfers on blockchain

Tags: web3js, python

How do I get all transfers occurring on the blockchain and their transaction amounts and to and from addresses?

```
event_signature_hash = web3.keccak(text='Transfer(address,address,uint256)').hex()
event_filter = web3.eth.filter({
    'fromBlock': "latest",
    'topics': [event_signature_hash]
})

import time
while True:
    events = web3.eth.get_filter_changes(event_filter.filter_id)
    for e in events:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I understood correctly the question.

You will see something like this as result `for e in events`.

I leave comments in this code to explain each part.

```py
AttributeDict({'address': '0x1EDD14eF98be4bBD920bb194C658De5D2204759E',  # this is the address of token that transferred
 'blockHash': HexBytes('0x22cc48ae994ff29b845c49cff29770cb0e4e770242fed211006d4d84fc21e61d'),
 'blockNumber': 9006097,
 'data': HexBytes('0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000025c11c'),  # this is data for this function. It is amount of transfer. 
 'logIndex': 2,
 'removed': False,
 'topics': [HexBytes('0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef'),  # This is a signature of `Transfer(address,address,uint256)`
  HexBytes('0x00000000000000000000000032fb699fe913e8e0b3196190673751dcf42800eb'),  # This is first `address`. It is a from wallet
  HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000')], # This is second `address`. It is a to wallet.
 'transactionHash': HexBytes('0xc1cfd0416db8938be5acb537df22b85029c5c27fabe3385803da24330748ed4f'),  # This is hash of transaction. You can check it with etherscan
 'transactionIndex': 1})
```

To handle leading 0'es, you could do smt like this:

```py
# from 0x00000000000000000000000032fb699fe913e8e0b3196190673751dcf42800eb
# to                           0x32fb699fe913e8e0b3196190673751dcf42800eb
web3.to_hex(web3.to_int(entry['topics'][1]))
```

Note:

1. If transfer to HexBytes('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'), it mean burn this amount of token.
2. 0xddf252ad.. happens as part of more complex smart contracts.

Take a look to this transaction via etherscan and switch to "Logs" section:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xc1cfd0416db8938be5acb537df22b85029c5c27fabe3385803da24330748ed4f#eventlog

Comment: Fantastic answer thank you.